# Adding diagonal line to connect paired data points organized by group in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several paired data points, representing the mean observation of various groups -/+ treatment, and I'd like to plot them side-by-side, organized by groups, with diagonal lines connecting the paired observations. Here is a toy example of the data, and what I have managed to come up with so far for graphing.

```
counts.example <- tibble(line=c('line1','line1','line2','line2'),
                         treatment=c('no','yes','no','yes'), 
                         counts=c(150, 2000, 250, 300))
ggplot(counts.example, aes(x=line, y=counts)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
ggplot(counts.example, aes(x=1:nrow(counts.example), y=counts, group=line)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

The first example give the paired points aligned vertically, with the correct `line` labels underneath.

[image]

The second example has the desired staggered/diagonal organization, but it's kludgy and also doesn't permit labeling by `line`.

[image]

I suspect there is a simple and elegant way to do this with ggplot, but I haven't figured it out yet. Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: If you want a legend for the lines, use `shape = line` or `color = line` inside the `aes`. You use `group` which by default doesn't make a legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you can facet your plot and modify the facetting labeling to mimick the use of `line` as x labeling:

```r
ggplot(counts.example, 
       aes(x= treatment, y = counts, group = line))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~line, switch = "x")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(-1,"lines"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: This was perfect - especially once I used `cowplot` to convert to a more publication-ish plot layout, it looked exactly the way I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a manual dodge, use a continuous axis and fake a discrete axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)
counts.example <- tibble(line=c('line1','line1','line2','line2'),
                         treatment=c('no','yes','no','yes'), 
                         counts=c(150, 2000, 250, 300))

counts_df <- counts.example %>%
  mutate(dodged = ifelse(treatment == 'no', 
                         as.numeric(as.factor(line))-0.1,
                         as.numeric(as.factor(line))+0.1))

ggplot(counts_df, aes(x=dodged, y=counts)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes( group = line)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = unique(counts_df$line))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But may I allow myself to suggest a simpler and possibly more convincing way of visualising your data. With the connecting lines - a fancy feature on a plot - you want to visualise change. But why not visualising it directly. I assume that this is what your story is about..
I am using geom_point, but as you are showing counts, you could actually use bar plots!

```r
counts_wide <- counts.example %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "treatment", values_from = "counts") %>%
  mutate(change = yes-no)

ggplot(counts_wide, aes(x=no, y=change)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = line)) +
  labs(x = 'Baseline count')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - the manual dodge is definitely a reasonable solution. I think the direct plot of baseline vs change might not be the best way to visualize my actual data, but I will try it also.